# youtube-dl how to call PowerShell script with all possible filenames

Tags: powershell, youtube-dl

I wrote a PowerShell script to do some post processing on audio downloaded by youtube-dl and I'm trying to use the `--exec` flag to call it automatically. The problem is that I don't know how to properly do it so it works with all possible filenames.

Command that works exept for Video titles with `'` or `()` in them:

```
PS > youtube-dl -i -f bestaudio --exec 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "{}"' https://youtu.be/zRunkRiylvM
[youtube] zRunkRiylvM: Downloading webpage
[youtube] zRunkRiylvM: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Dream Big, Princess – Live Your Story (Official Lyric Video) _ Disney-zRunkRiylvM.webm has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 3.14MiB
[exec] Executing command: powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "Dream Big, Princess – Live Your Story (Official Lyric Video) _ Disney-zRunkRiylvM.webm"
Official : The term 'Official' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:78
+ ... Normalize.ps1 Dream Big, Princess – Live Your Story (Official Lyric V ...
+                                                          ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Official:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

ERROR: Command returned error code 1

PS > youtube-dl -i -f bestaudio --exec 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "{}"' https://youtu.be/tTuwo_TqlhQ
[youtube] tTuwo_TqlhQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] tTuwo_TqlhQ: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Destination: Tangled Lyric Video _ I've Got A Dream _ Sing Along-tTuwo_TqlhQ.m4a
[download] 100% of 3.05MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "Tangled Lyric Video _ I've Got A Dream _ Sing Along-tTuwo_TqlhQ.m4a"
[exec] Executing command: powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "Tangled Lyric Video _ I've Got A Dream _ Sing Along-tTuwo_TqlhQ.m4a"
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

ERROR: Command returned error code 1
```

And a command that only breaks for Videos with `'` in the title:

```
PS > youtube-dl -i -f bestaudio --exec "powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 '{}'" https://youtu.be/tTuwo_TqlhQ
[youtube] tTuwo_TqlhQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] tTuwo_TqlhQ: Downloading video info webpage
[download] Tangled Lyric Video _ I've Got A Dream _ Sing Along-tTuwo_TqlhQ.m4a has already been downloaded
[download] 100% of 3.05MiB
[ffmpeg] Correcting container in "Tangled Lyric Video _ I've Got A Dream _ Sing Along-tTuwo_TqlhQ.m4a"
[exec] Executing command: powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 '"Tangled Lyric Video _ I've Got A Dream _ Sing Along-tTuwo_TqlhQ.m4a"'
The string is missing the terminator: '.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TerminatorExpectedAtEndOfString

ERROR: Command returned error code 1
```

How can I get it to work with these and maybe other edge cases that I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-File` flag for powershell works:

```
youtube-dl -i -f bestaudio --exec 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File D:\PowerShell\ConvertAndNormalize.ps1 "{}"' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpSnlSGciSWPBUsHQKmXGX3TB-FTSO0U6
```